# Reading CSV File Using Jet - TabDelimited Does Not Workl!

Tags: c#

This has been killing me - I have a massive file that I need to read in as a DataTable.

After a lot of messing about I am using this:

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
{
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
        {
            dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        }
    }
}
```

which works if the text file is comma seperated but does not work if it is tab delimited - Can anyone please help??

My connection string looks like :

`string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly + @";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES'";`

I ve tried to set the FMT property with no luck....

Comment: Have you tried creating a schema.ini in the same directory with the following section? 
[MyFilename.txt]  
Format=TabDelimited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good library use it.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

Here is the code which use the library.

```
TextReader tr = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Filename));
string data = tr.ReadToEnd();
tr.Close();
```

for comma delimited;

```
CachedCsvReader cr = new CachedCsvReader(new StringReader(csv), true);
```

for tab delimited;

```
CachedCsvReader cr = new CachedCsvReader(new StringReader(csv), true, '\t');
```

And here you can load it into **DataTable** by having this code

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cr);
```

Hope you find it helpful. Thanks

Comment: And also you can have the headeres of the csv file easily by just calling this function as a string array.

cr.GetFieldHeaders();

Comment: I have used this library with success, so giving it an up vote

Comment: yes it write the code for tab delimited just pass any file path which contain data in streamreader constructor

Answer (score 0):

Manually: You can use String.Split() method to split your entire file. Here is an example of what i use in my code.  In this example, i read the data line by line and split it.  I then place the data directly into columns.

```
                //Open and read the file
                System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("myfilename", System.IO.FileMode.Open);
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fs);

                string line = "";
                line = sr.ReadLine();

                string[] colVal;

                try
                {
                    //clear of previous data
                    //myDataTable.Clear();

                    //for each reccord insert it into a row
                    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        line = sr.ReadLine();

                            colVal = line.Split('\t');

                            DataRow dataRow = myDataTable.NewRow();

                            //associate values with the columns
                            dataRow["col1"] = colVal[0];        
                            dataRow["col2"] = colVal[1]; 
                            dataRow["col3"] = colVal[2]; 

                            //add the row to the table
                            myDataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                    }

                    //close the stream
                    sr.Close();

                    //binds the dataset tothe grid view.
                    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                    bs.DataSource = myDataSet;
                    bs.DataMember = myDataTable.TableName;
                    myGridView.DataSource = bs;
                }
```

You could modify it to do some loops for columns if you have many and they are numbered.  Also, i recommend checking the integrity first, by checking that the number of columns read is correct.

Answer (score -1):

This should work: (from http://www.hotblue.com/article0000.aspx?a=0006)

just replace the comma part with:

```
if ((postdata || !quoted) && (c == ',' || c == '\t'))
```

to make it tab delimited.

```
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public DataTable ParseCSV(string inputString) {

  DataTable dt=new DataTable();

  // declare the Regular Expression that will match versus the input string
  Regex re=new Regex("((?<field>[^\",\\r\\n]+)|\"(?<field>([^\"]|\"\")+)\")(,|(?<rowbreak>\\r\\n|\\n|$))");

  ArrayList colArray=new ArrayList();
  ArrayList rowArray=new ArrayList();

  int colCount=0;
  int maxColCount=0;
  string rowbreak="";
  string field="";

  MatchCollection mc=re.Matches(inputString);

  foreach(Match m in mc) {

    // retrieve the field and replace two double-quotes with a single double-quote
    field=m.Result("${field}").Replace("\"\"","\"");

    rowbreak=m.Result("${rowbreak}");

    if (field.Length > 0) {
      colArray.Add(field);                  
      colCount++;
    }

    if (rowbreak.Length > 0) {

      // add the column array to the row Array List
      rowArray.Add(colArray.ToArray());

      // create a new Array List to hold the field values
      colArray=new ArrayList(); 

      if (colCount > maxColCount)
        maxColCount=colCount;

      colCount=0;
    }
  }

  if (rowbreak.Length == 0) {
    // this is executed when the last line doesn't
    // end with a line break
    rowArray.Add(colArray.ToArray());
    if (colCount > maxColCount)
      maxColCount=colCount;
  }

  // create the columns for the table
  for(int i=0; i < maxColCount; i++)
  dt.Columns.Add(String.Format("col{0:000}",i));

  // convert the row Array List into an Array object for easier access
  Array ra=rowArray.ToArray();
  for(int i=0; i < ra.Length; i++) {                

    // create a new DataRow
    DataRow dr=dt.NewRow();

    // convert the column Array List into an Array object for easier access
    Array ca=(Array)(ra.GetValue(i));               

    // add each field into the new DataRow
    for(int j=0; j < ca.Length; j++)
      dr[j]=ca.GetValue(j);

    // add the new DataRow to the DataTable
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
  }

  // in case no data was parsed, create a single column
  if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
    dt.Columns.Add("NoData");

  return dt;
}
```

Now that we have a parser for converting a string into a DataTable, all we need now is a function that will read the content from a CSV file and pass it to our ParseCSV function:

```
public DataTable ParseCSVFile(string path) {

  string inputString="";

  // check that the file exists before opening it
  if (File.Exists(path)) {

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
    inputString = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();

  }

  return ParseCSV(inputString);
}
```

And now you can easily fill a DataGrid with data coming off the CSV file:

```
protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid DataGrid1;

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {

  // call the parser
  DataTable dt=ParseCSVFile(Server.MapPath("./demo.csv"));          

  // bind the resulting DataTable to a DataGrid Web Control
  DataGrid1.DataSource=dt;
  DataGrid1.DataBind();
}
```